# How to access an SQLite database file stored on cd using php?

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a small mySQL database and a few simple php based webpages that query the database, generate html tables and present them in the browser.  The database is no longer being updated.  So, searching and viewing subsets of the data is all that is required.

Some users are interested in distributing the searchable database on a cd or usb memory stick.  SQLite seems to offer the answer, but I don't understand what is needed to make this work. What will be required to make a web browser based "app" work from a memory stick in the absence of a server like xampp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAMPP Lite from http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  With this, I don't even need to convert to SQLite. It will work with my existing mySQL setup!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a "standalone server". This is very common in almost every other modern language except PHP, for some reason. Googling "standalone php server" reveals several options:

- [QuickPHP](http://www.zachsaw.com/?pg=quickphp_php_tester_debugger)
- [Nanoweb](http://nanoweb.si.kz/)
- [Server2Go](http://www.server2go-web.de/)

Comment: Cool, the XAMPP Lite answer got +1 and this gets -1 for no particular reasons.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to vote on anything.  Sorry.  They all look good. I'd like to see Server2Go for  Mac get out of beta.